# Comparing parallel arrays read from a text file

Tags: c++, arrays, function, file

I have a question about using two parallel arrays.

For example, I read in 20 characters from a text file into a character array. Then I read in 20 different characters from another text file with a different character array.

**How can I compare the two and see if they match?**

This is a separate function from the main, so this function will be passed on the arrays from main.

Comment: review std::string and std::string::operator ==().

Comment: not quite sure what you mean by that

Comment: std::string is the C++ version of a char array ... this std library template has an operator "==", i.e. a method that returns true when 2 identical strings are compared, and false otherwise.  Did I misread your "How can I compare the two and see if they match?"  I interpreted it as "How can I compare the two 'std::strings' and determine that they match?"

Comment: right now i have them initialized as char array, for example its initialized as, char answers[20]. And i have a loop reading in from a text file into each of the cells. and one that reads into, student answers[20]. and im trying to determine how many are wrong and right using the arrays

Comment: Perhaps "int strncmp( const char* lhs, const char* rhs, size_t count );" is the C style solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually extremely easy (in case anyone else was wondering)

All i did was create a for loop, and inside the loop created an if statement where i called in the corresponding cells of each. If they were not equal i made a counter of how many were wrong, and displayed it at the end.

And if the questions were right do nothing.

I don't know if i explained it super well. I'm still super new to programming and i gotta say the feeling of figuring something out on your own after a lot of work feels really good :).

Thanks for the replys.